# rails session store sets cookie with wrong domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

We are using rails with devise to provide user authentication.
Recently we changed the domain of the cookie_store in the
session_store configuration to .example.com. Everything worked as
expected, the cookies are created correctly.

Now in rare cases we get the session cookie with domain
subdomain.example.com. This happens along with a rack.session cookie
also with the wrong domain.

Because we can't explain why sometimes the cookie has the full domain,
we suspect it to be related with the rack.session cookie. We couldn't
find when the rack.session cookie is set. I logged in in via devise
and no rack.session cookie was set.

Does anybody had the same error where the session cookie is set under
the wrong domain? It would be helpful to understand in which cases the
rack.session cookie is set.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like sidekiq-ui caused the problem. 
When visiting the ui rack.session and the session cookie were set with the wrong domain.

That can be solved with following configuration in config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

`Sidekiq::Web.set :sessions, domain: 'all'`

Comment: Thank you for this! Saved me a painful debug session...